# Smarty {html_radio} how to make it required?

Tags: html, radio-button, smarty, prestashop

I'm looking for how to make a radio-buttons group required using the smarty custom function {html_radio} http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.radios.tpl

Here is my code :

```
{html_radios name='radio' options=$radio_options separator='<br />'}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digged into function.html_radios.php from tools/smarty/ and saw the $extra var.

```
if (!is_array($_val)) {
   $extra .= ' ' . $_key . '="' . smarty_function_escape_special_chars($_val) . '"';
}
```

Also, in http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.radios.tpl, see the "strict" attribute.

So, my code looks like :

```
{html_radios required='required' name='radio' options=$radio_options separator='<br />'}
```

And it works great.